# How are enter() and exit() detecting updated data in D3?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, d3.js

I am building a small UI where the user has to select a point on each of the two SVGs shown.

These points coordinates are then shown under the SVGs. I would like to achieve this using D3's data-binding with the `enter()` and `exit()` methods. However it seems that D3 doesn't always update the part where I display the points coordinates, even if I call the `enter()` method on the bound elements. When removing data, the `exit()` methods works however.

Here is the main code :

```
function showPoints() {
  var coordinatesElements = d3.select('#coordinates').selectAll('.point').data(points);
  coordinatesElements.enter().append('div').classed('point', true)
    .text(function (d) {
      var textParts = [];
      if (d.firstSvg) { textParts.push('first : '+JSON.stringify(d.firstSvg)); }
      if (d.secondSvg) { textParts.push('second : '+JSON.stringify(d.secondSvg)); }
      return textParts.join(' - ');
    })
    .append("span")
    .classed('removeCalibrationPoint', true)
    .html("&nbsp;X")
    .on('click', function(d, i) {
      points.splice(i, 1);
      showPoints();
    });

  coordinatesElements.exit().remove();
}
```

I have created a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/rikatajaju/2/edit?html,js,output) fiddle that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you have an empty `div` of class `point` in your HTML. This will be selected by the `.selectAll('.point')` and cause the first element in your data not to show up.

The second problem is that you're not handling the update selection -- in some cases, you're not adding new data, but modifying existing data. The following code updates the text for the data in the update selection.

```
coordinatesElements.text(function (d) {
  var textParts = [];
  if (d.firstSvg) { textParts.push('first : '+JSON.stringify(d.firstSvg)); }
  if (d.secondSvg) { textParts.push('second : '+JSON.stringify(d.secondSvg)); }
  return textParts.join(' - ');
});
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsbin.com/nulatuqoha/1/edit?html,js,output). Notice I've simplified the code slightly by setting the text only on the update selection -- elements added from the enter selection merge into the update selection, so there's no need to do it twice.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer Lars. I understand the first problem, but I'm a bit confused about the second one. I see that your code is working as expected, but when diffing our mutual codes I notice that you just moved the `text()` callback further down in the function, I don't understand how this operation would change anything about the nodes' update.

Comment: `coordinatesElements` is the update selection -- you don't need to call an additional function like `.enter()` or `.exit()`. So by moving the code, I'm running the function that sets the text on the update selection, which at that point also contains the new elements that have been added from the `.enter()` selection.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I just noticed that your updated code made the "X" symbol allowing to remove a pair of coordinates be overwritten by the `text()` call. [Here is the final working code](http://jsbin.com/voxuka/1/).